# Find the Error on a disproof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

I was given the following problem by my instructor:

“Let g (x) be a specific antiderivative of $f(x)$, that is,

$g′ (x) = f (x)$

Then we can write

$\int_a^xf(x)dt=g(x)$ for some $a$

(This is in your book, so don’t go denying it!)
So look at this. Let $g (x) = \sin x + 5$, and $f (x) = \cos x$. Clearly $g′ (x) = f (x)$. The Fundamental
Theorem of Calculus then says that we can write

$\int_a^x \cos t dt = g (x)$
$\sin x − \sin a = \sin x + 5$
$\sin a = −5$

But $\sin a$ is never $-5$!

Find the error.

I believe they got it from [this site](http://uni.dougshaw.com/findtheerror/FTEanti.html). Can someone give me some help?

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_a^x g'(t) \mathrm{d}t  = g(x)-g(a)$

Comment: The claim which we are meant not to deny is false.  You can achieve the same "counterexample" with $F(x)=2x$, $G(x)=x^2+1$ or, indeed, any $G$ which has no roots.

Comment: If your book really asserts that $\int_a^xg'(t)\,\mathrm dt=g(x)$, then throw it away.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: indeed there are many books targeted for a first course in calculus which need to be thrown away. Luckily there is hope available on mathse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'$\int_a^{x}f(t)dt=g(x)$ for some $a$' is true only if $g(a)=0$ for some $a$. But in your example $g(a) \neq 0$ for any real number $a$ (since $g(a) \geq 4$ for all $a$).

Answer (score 1):

Note if $f$ is integrable and $g’(x)=f(x)$ then $\int_{a}^x f(x) = g(x)-g(a)$ you are missing the $-g(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if we define:
$$g'(x)=f(x)$$
then:
$$\int_a^xf(t)\,dt=\int_a^xg'(t)\,dt=\left[g(t)\right]_{t=a}^x=g(x)-g(a)$$
so maybe it was a typo and the writer meant "for whenever $g(a)=0"$ but it is certainly not true in general.

---

What the book is really saying is that if:
$$\left[g(x)-g(a)\right]'=[g(x)]'$$
$$\Rightarrow g(x)-g(a)=g(x)$$
and this is clearly only true for one case